# Using LUIS/IntentDialogs - How to get the utterance programmatically

Tags: botframework

I'm using LUIS to drive my v3 NodeJS bot's dialogs.

For every step in a waterfall, the function method is like this:

```
function (session, args) { ... }
```

From within the bot code I would like to programatically access the actual utterance the user wrote to the bot, so I can store it for audit purposes, or to pass it to other Cognitive services.

How can I access this utterance programatically?

Comment: One approach might be to set up a prompt manually, and then pipe it through the LUIS recognizer manually (see https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/462). This is kind of annoying since in my case I only need to access the raw utterance in one instance, yet have to refactor all my dialogs!

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, its actually very straight forward. You can access the session.message.text variable which contains the utterance.

Working NodeJS code example:

```
intents.matches('Start', function (session, args) {
    console.log("Msg text: " + session.message.text);
    session.send("Hi, let's begin");
});
```